# Twitterの画像表示バグ（？）の原因・原理について

Tags: twitter

プログラミングを勉強しているので、この原因、原理について教えていただきたいです。
Twitterを使っていたところ、他人の投稿した画像に色とりどりの変なカラーの縦線が入っており、
画像が半分左に押しのけられて潰れて？いました。
画像をタップして全画面表示にしたところ、その色が変わりました。
これは、どのような原因でこのようなことになってしまうのでしょうか。
スクリーンショットを撮影しようとしましたが、うまく行きませんでした。
よろしくお願いします。
他の画像ではこのような現象は起きず、この画像のみでした。

アプリ：Android版 Twitter 9.84.0 release.2
スマホ：Xperia SO-0K(Android10)